# Java : Occurances of a character in a String

Tags: java, loops

I need help on my code in Java.

This is the problem :

Example input : AaaaaAa

Output : A appears 7.

The problem is I need it to ignore cases.

Please help me, my code works fine, except that it doesn't ignore cases.

```
import java.io.*;

public class letter_bmp{
    public static BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception

    {

    String string1;
    String pick;

    String ans;
    do
    {
    int count=0;
    System.out.print("En taro Adun, Executor! Input desired string : ");
    string1 = input.readLine();
    System.out.print("Now, Executor...which character shall I choose : ");
    pick = input.readLine();

    for(int counter = 0; counter < string1.length(); counter++)
        {
        if(pick.charAt(0) == string1.charAt(counter))
        count++;
        }
    System.out.print("Executor...you picked '" + pick + "' it is used " + count + " times in the word "+string1+".");

    System.out.println("\nWould you like to try again, Executor? (Yes/No): ");
    ans = input.readLine();
    }
    while(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see that I put something like that there.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to lower case characters using the [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) method.

```
// ...
string1 = input.readLine().toLowerCase();
// ...
pick = input.readLine().toLowerCase();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make 2 new strings like this:

```
string1_lower = string1.toLowerCase();
pick_lower = pick.toLowerCase();
```

And use those two variables during comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the question is old and the OP might have got his answer. But i am putting this out here just in case if anybody needs it in the future.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="rEmember";

    for(int i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1; i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= s.length() - 1; j++){
            if(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)) == Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(j))){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i) + " = " + count + " times");
    }

}
```